# How do I strip section header table in an ELF file?

Tags: linux, reverse-engineering, elf

I am new to ELF binary protection.

I want to strip section header table to avoid debugging.

I try to find section header table offset on disk by run readelf -h, and try to nop them, but they are all 0.

How can I strip section header table?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First of all you can check which sections are present in your elf with `readelf --section-headers`. You should see something like this:

```
$ readelf --section-headers <your-file>

[ #] Name               Type            Address            Offset
     Size              Size.Ent         Flags     -     -  Alignment
[ 0]                   NULL             0000000000000000  00000000
     0000000000000000  0000000000000000           0     0     0
[ 1] .data             PROGBITS         00000000006000b0  000000b0
     000000000000003b  0000000000000000  WA       0     0     1
[ 2] .text             PROGBITS         0000000000a000f0  000000f0
     00000000000003e9  0000000000000000  AX       0     0     1
[ 3] .shstrtab         STRTAB           0000000000000000  000004d9
     0000000000000027  0000000000000000           0     0     1
[ 4] .symtab           SYMTAB           0000000000000000  00000680
     0000000000000438  0000000000000018           5    41     8
[ 5] .strtab           STRTAB           0000000000000000  00000ab8
     0000000000000258  0000000000000000           0     0     1
```

And you should be aware that most of sections are added by linker since the only real parts you need in your binary are `.text` and `.data`. Most of other information can be omitted if you do linkage manually.

If you are using classic `ld` linker, i would recommend trying options `--strip-all` and `--strip-debug`. As name suggests, they remove debug-info and other symbolic information from binary - [here](https://linux.die.net/man/1/ld) you can see the docs.

```
$ readelf --section-headers <your-file>

[ #] Name               Type            Address            Offset
     Size              Size.Ent         Flags     -     -  Alignment
[ 0]                   NULL             0000000000000000  00000000
     0000000000000000  0000000000000000           0     0     0
[ 1] .data             PROGBITS         00000000006000b0  000000b0
     000000000000003b  0000000000000000  WA       0     0     1
[ 2] .text             PROGBITS         0000000000a000f0  000000f0
     00000000000003e9  0000000000000000  AX       0     0     1
[ 3] .shstrtab         STRTAB           0000000000000000  000004d9
     0000000000000017  0000000000000000           0     0     1
```

But by now you should probably have only 3 sections and since most of the data is already omitted, you can stop at that point - now your `.shstrtab` only contains names of text and data sections - it's not really a secret it does :)

And now it really depends on how far you are ready to go.

If you would like to proceed, i would suggest trying another tool called `strip` (from binutils) which you can use like this: `strip --remove-section=shstrtab <your-file>` - it basically removes the undesired section but it's not that easy to get rid of `.shstrtab` as i remember using it.

You can even try removing it by yourself - since you know exact offset of section (and it's probably at the very end of file), you can just place zeroes over it aka "renaming" sections to null :)

And according to ELF specs shstrtab is not required for execution so you should be ok even if you manually remove it from file (removing those bytes) - just keep other pointers,offsets,etc valid

---

In my case removing debug info was ok so i didn't go that far but you can - I would just wish you good luck :)

Answer (score 0):

You can download the Upx packer. Then, when you will run `objdump -fs` you'll have something link this :

```
ransom:     file format elf64-x86-64
architecture: i386:x86-64, flags 0x00000140:
DYNAMIC, D_PAGED
start address 0x0000000000003190
```

With nothing else.