# Under what circumstances, if any, would an executable ELF file (type == EXEC) not have section headers?

Tags: elf

Reading the ELF specification, it seems that for an EXEC type ELF file, the section header table is listed as "optional". Under what circumstances would it be omitted?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Under what circumstances would it be omitted?

Section info is not needed at execution time, and traditionally is only kept for debugging (e.g. you can get a backtrace for a crash from an executable compiled without any debugging info).

You should be able to remove them with e.g. `strip --strip-all`, but that doesn't appear to work.

You could also binary-patch the the file -- e.g. zero out `.e_shoff` and `.e_shnum` in the ELF header.

[Related answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62258859/50617).

Comment: Fair enough, but what about in the ELF file itself? As I understand it the section headers are listed as optional in the specification, but I've never made one without them. When do they get omitted during the creation of the ELF file?

Comment: @MichaelStachowsky I don't understand. Like I said above, normally they _don't_ get omitted, but you could construct a valid ELF without them. E.g. you could create an ELF file "by hand" -- there is an example of this on stackoverflow, but I can't find it.

Comment: I think that basically answers it then. I was sort of wondering what would make a compiler not include those headers, but it seems that they basically always would regardless of whether they are necessary. Thanks!